# Error Condition if in C++

Tags: c++

I Have a script c++
but i running this script

This script error when i write code shirt "GC" or  "PR"

but i write code "A" this script working

why ?

whether if / else if condition only 1 character ?

This is my script, help me. Thank's

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
main()
{
char code,size,merk[15];
long price=0;
clrscr();

cout <<"\n \t GUCCI : GC";
cout <<"\n \t PRADA : PR \n";
cout <<"\n \t Armani : A";
cout <<"\n";

cout<<"Choose Your Shirt : ";cin>>code;
cout<<"Size : ";cin>>size;

if (code=='GC' || code=='gc')
{
strcpy(merk,"Gucci");

    if (size=='S' || size =='s')
        price=45000;

   else if (size=='L' || size =='l')
        price=35000;

    else if (size=='M' || size =='m')
        price=45000;

    else
        price=60000;
}

else if (code=='PR' || code=='pr')
{
strcpy(merk,"PRADA");

    if (size=='S' || size == 's')
        price=65000;


   else if (size=='L' || size =='l')
        price=75000;

    else if (size=='M' || size =='m')
        price=85000;

    else

    price=75000;
}

else if (code=='A' || code=='a')
{
strcpy(merk,"ARMANI");

    if (size=='S' || size == 's')
        price=75000;


   else if (size=='L' || size =='l')
        price=95000;

    else if (size=='M' || size =='m')
        price=45000;

    else

    price=35000;
}

else
{
cout<<"Wrong Code"<<endl;
}

cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Merk  : "<<merk<<endl;
cout<<"Price : "<<price<<endl;
getch();
}
```

Comment: The term "script" is usually reserved for interpreted languages.

Comment: Hint: `sizeof(char)==1`. `std::string` could be helpful.

Comment: I confused, i'm new learn in C++

Answer (score 2):

`code=='GC'` single quotes are for single characters (which "GC" is not). Use double quotes for "strings" (but remember you can't compare strings with `==`)...

Since you only read one character at a time, how did you expect to enter "GC"?

Comment: Of course you __can__ compare `string`s with `==`! Since the author is apparently new to the language, mentioning `string` should be mandatory in order to pass some new knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

John3136 is right.
You might want to simply the code to tolower() on your input ("code").
All you would need to do is compare to the lower case.
Using switch statement, instead of all those if statements, eould
make your code more readable.

For comparing multiple characters, use either string, strcmp or stricmp.

Comment: i don't understand

give me example plis